# ASP.NET Radio Button List | SelectedValue coming up NULL

Tags: c#, server-side, radiobuttonlist

I posted a similar RBL question but I have a new issue arising so I figured I'd make a new post.

Here is my code:

Page_Load

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Output Success/Error Message
    if (Session["formProcessed"] != null)
    {
        Label lblMessage = (Label)Master.FindControl("lblMessage");
        new Global().DisplayUserMessage("success", Session["formProcessed"].ToString(), lblMessage);
    }
    Session.Remove("formProcessed");

    if (Page.IsPostBack == false)
    {
        rblContentTypesGetAll.DataBind();
    }
}
```

rblContentTypesGetAll_Load

```
 protected void rblContentTypesGetAll_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(Global.conString))
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("contentTypeGetAll", con))
        using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
        {
            da.Fill(dt);
        }
        //Clear Items before reloading
        rblContentTypesGetAll.Items.Clear();

        //Populate Radio button list
        for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            rblContentTypesGetAll.Items.Add(new ListItem(dt.Rows[i]["contentType"].ToString() + " - " + dt.Rows[i]["description"].ToString(),
                dt.Rows[i]["ID"].ToString()));
        }

        //Set Default Selected Item by Value
        rblContentTypesGetAll.SelectedIndex = rblContentTypesGetAll.Items.IndexOf(rblContentTypesGetAll.Items.FindByValue(((siteParams)Session["myParams"]).DefaultContentType.ToLower()));
    }

}
```

HTML/ASP.NET front end

```
 <asp:RadioButtonList id="rblContentTypesGetAll" OnLoad="rblContentTypesGetAll_Load"  runat="server">
        </asp:RadioButtonList>
```

As soon as I submit the form it seems the `selectedValue` becomes blank. What am I doing that's so obviously incorrect?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although all of you were helpful, the issue was much deeper. I had viewState disabled.

Comment: I want to kill the `view-state`

Answer (score 1):

All the code in your `Page_Load` needs to be inside:

```
if(Page.IsPostBack  == false)
```

You are re-filling the list when the page is submitted causing the list to be repopulated and hence losing the previous items including which one was selected.

> http://gurustop.net

Comment: It seems the value disappears immediately after pressing the submit button. I wrapped the DataBind in what you posted above.

Answer (score 0):

Try by filling your required binding in page_load don't forgot to use  (!IsPostBack)

Comment: What i asked is to bind in page load instead of radio button load

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I think that could be happening is when you set the original selected index here:

```
rblContentTypesGetAll.SelectedIndex = rblContentTypesGetAll.Items.IndexOf(rblContentTypesGetAll.Items.FindByValue(((siteParams)Session["myParams"]).DefaultContentType.ToLower()));
```

it might not be finding the value and then setting it to "-1".  Then if you don't ever select a radio button on the page you would get no selected value.

I tried this and it seemed fine:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            //Pretending to call your stored proc..
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("contentType");
            dt.Columns.Add("description");
            dt.Columns.Add("ID");
            dt.AcceptChanges();
            for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
            {
                DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
                dr["contentType"] = "cnt" + i.ToString();
                dr["description"] = "desc" + i.ToString();
                dr["ID"] = i.ToString();
                dt.Rows.Add(dr);
            }


            //Populate Radio button list
            for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                rblContentTypesGetAll.Items.Add(new ListItem(dt.Rows[i]["contentType"].ToString() + " - " + dt.Rows[i]["description"].ToString(),
                    dt.Rows[i]["ID"].ToString()));
            }

            //Set Default Selected Item by Value
            rblContentTypesGetAll.SelectedIndex = 0; //this could be -1 also
        }

        lblMessage.Text = "rblContentTypesGetAll.SelectedValue :" + rblContentTypesGetAll.SelectedValue;

    }
```

Comment: So weird...I feel like this issue is so simple. I tried this and it still was submitting a blank value. The list populates and the values have value. I don't know what causes the list to disappear.

Comment: The selected value is deleting immediately after pressing submit before it even goes through the code behind

Comment: There must be something missing, try taking off the master page and any javascript not shown, the code above works so there's some outside code messing with the radio button list.